# finding row in table based off text in a table row, output view link

Tags: javascript, html-table

the table i am trying to get data from is being a bit difficult. I have search text that i can input into the javascript. I want to search the table, specifically the title column for this search text. In this example i want to find asat. I then want to return the view href. Please note i am in no control of the html and i would like to run the code using javascript.  I have included 2 variations of functions I was trying to get it to work

```js
function myFunction() {
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".list td a");
    var search = "asat";
    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i){
    // This line checks for an exact match in a cell against what the
    // user entered in the search box
    //if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase() === search.value.toLowerCase()){
    
    // This checks for cells that start with what the user has entered
    if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === 0){      
        cells.forEach(function(element){
            element.style.display = "none";
        });
        cells[i].style.background = "yellow";
        cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
        break;
    } else {
        cells[i].style.background = "white";
        cells.forEach(function(element){
          if(cells[i] !== element){
            element.style.display = "table-cell";
          }
        }); 
    }    
  }
}
myFunction();
/*function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue;
  input = "as";
  filter = input.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      tda = td.getElementsByTagName("a");
      if (tda) {
         for (j = 0; j < tda.length; j++) {
             txtValue = tda.textContent || tda.innerText;
         } 
      }   
      else {
         txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      }
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
myFunction2();  */
```

```html
<table class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="headerRow"><th class="actionColumn" scope="col">Action</th><th scope="col" class=" zen-deemphasize">Type</th><th scope="col" class=" zen-deemphasize">Title</th><th scope="col" class=" zen-deemphasize">Last Modified</th><th scope="col" class=" zen-deemphasize">Created By</th></tr>

<!-- ListRow -->
<tr class="dataRow even first">
  <td class="actionColumn">
    <a>Edit</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="/1122">View</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a>Del</a></td>
  <th scope="row" class=" dataCell  ">Attachment</th>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">
    <a>TS ASAT V3.0 - REV 3.xlsm</a>
  </td>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">10/29/2020 2:15 PM
  </td>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">
    <a>Will</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- ListRow -->
<tr class="dataRow odd">
  <td class="actionColumn">
    <a>Edit</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a>View</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a>Del</a></td>
  <th scope="row" class=" dataCell  ">Attachment</th>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">
    <a href="/00P2S00001FV3Ou">LEWISTON - NESG.pdf
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">10/29/2020 1:55 PM
  </td>
  <td class=" dataCell  ">
    <a href="/0052S000009gWvi">Will
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed your search condition to use -1 and optimized the loop.

```
function extractRefs() {
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".list td a");
  const search = "asat";
  const hrefs = [];

  for (var i = 3; i < cells.length; i += 3) {
    const cell = cells[i];
    if (cell.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      if (cells[i - 2].href) {
        hrefs.push(cells[i - 2].href);
      }
      cell.style.background = "yellow";
    } else {
      cell.style.background = "white";
    }
  }

  console.log(hrefs);
}
```